# Question marks instead of cyrillic on Mac

Tags: babel, texshop, input-encodings, font-encodings, cyrillic

I need to include one sentence in Russian to an English-only document. I use TexShop on MacOS.

I do have the following commands in my document:

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

But I still get question marks instead of cyrillic symbols. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a piece of document code that shows the issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Btw: It's 2015 and we have _two_ TeX-engines capable of handling Unicode and OpenType fonts (LuaTeX and XeTeX). Use one of them.

Comment: @MartinSchröder the vast majority of tex use (and almost all journal submission requirements) use pdftex, while a suggestion to try xe/lua tex might be good, The suggestion in your comment that it is wrong or outdated to be using tex seems very misplaced.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use encoding properly, you need to change the system encoding. Go to Preferences --> Find "Encoding" and change that to "UTF-8". That should work.
Here is a screen of that:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that Mac was using its own encodings by default. The problem is solved.